# Best way to get 64 bit value of __libc_stack_end?

Tags: x86, gdb, x86-64

My system is x86_64 and trying to get 64 bit value od __libc_stack_end. How can I get 64 bit value of __libc_stack_end ?

```
(gdb) p $rbp
$7 = (void *) 0x7fff44f99620
(gdb) p /x __libc_stack_end
$8 = 0x44f9b120
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(gdb) x/g &__libc_stack_end
0x2abe0e9f6e38 <__libc_stack_end>:      0x00007fff1a104610
```